# How to serve static files from a Dockerized Python web app?

Tags: python, docker, containers, portability, dockerfile

I have a Python web application that sits behind Nginx, and is served via Gunicorn.

I have configured it so that Nginx servers static files directly from the disk and it only talks to Gunicorn for static assets such as images.

**My questions:**

1. Is it a good idea or a big "no" to dockerize the web app together with static assets?
2. If I want to deploy my container in 2 servers, which need access to same assets, how can I make the static assets portable just like the containerized app?

**What I'd like to have if possible:**

I'd like to put my app in a container and I would like to make it as portable as possible, without spending more funds on additional resources such as a separate server to keep the images (like a DB)

Answer (score 6):

If you know your app will always-and-forever have the same static assets, then just containerize them with the app and be done with it.

But things change, so when you need it I would recommend a [Docker Volume Container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) approach: put your static assets in a DVC and mount that DVC in the main container so it's all pretty much "just one app container". You could use Docker Compose something like this:

```
appdata:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
        - /path/to/app/static
    command: echo "I'm just a volume container"
app:
    build: .
    volumes_from:
        - appdata
    command: …
```

You can expand further by starting your container with a bootstrap script that copies initial static files into the destination path on startup. That way your app is guaranteed to always have a default set to get started, but you can add more static files as the app grows. For an example of this, pull the official Jenkins container and read `/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh`.

Comment: This sounds like a very nice idea. I will check out the DVC approach. In the meantime, if you can please, could you elaborate on the answer focusing on how to handle uploaded images that a web-app might have? Imagine adding product images or images to a blogpost that should scale (portability) like the containers on multiple machines and that are easy to carry from machine to machine. How can that be done? Thanks!

Comment: @Phil if you have a single Docker host, then all your app containers can share the DVC to access the static media. If you have multiple Docker hosts, as most large-scale production Docker systems do, then the answer is non-trivial.

Comment: The former is "non-trivial". The latter is what I'm asking to learn and understand in my original question.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with kojiro, if things do not change much, containerize the static files with your app. Regarding your second question, it seems that you think the Docker Volume Container approach is still not flexible enough since you will have multiple docker hosts. Maybe Flocker addresses your requirements? From the Flocker docs (https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/0.3.2/):

> Flocker lets you move your Docker containers and their data together
>   between Linux hosts. This means that you can run your databases,
>   queues and key-value stores in Docker and move them around as easily
>   as the rest of your app. Even stateless apps depend on many stateful
>   services and currently running these services in Docker containers in
>   production is nearly impossible. Flocker aims to solve this problem by
>   providing an orchestration framework that allows you to port both your
>   stateful and stateless containers between environments.

Comment: ikkjo, is it safe to assume that this is a problem that is yet to be universally solved than? porting / sharing / serving constantly changing static assets (eg, uploaded images)? I will check out flocker btw --> thanks!

Comment: At least from what I understand this is not universally solved. I am not sure that it will be either. Even if you were running on a traditional cluster without docker you would have different options regarding what to do about data and data replication depending on your needs, I guess this is the same in the docker world where implementation is a trade-off between different requirements.

Comment: I see. So off to spending lots of money on CDNs then.